# Apple script for switching user from login window

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript

I have the following Apple script to switch the user account. This works fine if we are logged in to any user account and trying to switch to other accounts.

If we are in the login window screen ([the screen where we can see all the user accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR9Yx.jpg)), the Apple script doesn't work. Any idea how to do this?

```
set theUser to "test"    --  Mac User name 
set thePassword to "test@123" -- Mac user password
set theUser to do shell script "/usr/bin/id -u " & theUser  
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/'Menu Extras'/user.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -switchToUserID " & theUser  
repeat 2 times      
    delay 2
        try
                tell application "System Events"
                    tell process "SecurityAgent"                    
                        set value of text field 1 of window "Login" to thePassword
                        key code 36             
                    end tell
                end tell            
                exit repeat     
        on error            
            delay 1     
        end try 
end repeat
```

Is it possible to do this? If it can not be done by using Apple script is there any other way we can achieve this?